# How to setvalues from arraylist to array, split them and set split text in jtextfield

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split, jlist

I have tried to this code but the jtextfield turns out empty any help will be greatly appreciated. I think the problem is coming in where instead of manually specifying the location of textfile I use the jfilechooser but am not sure. Please somebody help me.

```
try {
        try {

               UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(doc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(doc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(doc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(doc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        try


        {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader (filename);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            jTextArea1.read(br, null);
            br.close();
            jTextArea1.requestFocus();
        }catch(Exception e){

            }
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String str;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(str);

        }
        String[] listArray =list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        for(int b=0; b<listArray.length;b++){
            String[] Arra= str.split(" ")
             serial_no.setText(Arra.get(0));
             adm_no.setText(Arra.get(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `BufferedReader` - `in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));` is incorrect as the filename is a string not a variable.

`str` contains the last read line in `String[] Arra= str.split(" ")` - is that what you want or `lst.get(i).split(" ")` would get you the words in the ith line

Comment: i noticed and did this instead-in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)); but still it does not work

Comment: Is there a reason for using `BufferedReader`, cause with `FileInputStream` you could use `File` directly - `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);`

Comment: i dont know how to read a text file line by line using the FileInputStream

Comment: So what is the content of the arraylist `list` ?

Comment: it should contain this line from the textfile - SNo: 2505942 , Pin No: 9930 1191 1813 6816 ,CHKCode: 44065 - and it should split it using the commas so that can get each block in its individual textfield

Comment: in `serial_no.setText` do you want to print the last read line or every line, because at the moment you have `str.split(" ");` where str is the last line read by `BufferedReader`